# Como mudar foto da capa

Tags: javascript, file-upload, image, background-image

Como atualizar foto dessa capa a partir de meu computador com javascript, button input type=" file" ou com nodejs.

[image: <img src="/uploads/default/original/3X/c/5/c5f4ea4fca6b922a1afcf66a0d5b70de69a877ad.png" width="690" height="383">]

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
    #teste {
        background-image: url('html.png');
        height: 250px;
        width: 900px;
        border: 1px solid black;    
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    button, input {
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="teste">
    <button style="font-size:24px">Atualizar foto de capa <i class="fa fa-camera"></i></button><br><br>
    <input type="file" name=""> 
</div>
    <h1>Página teste</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alterar a imagem em tempo real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para atualizar a imagem em tempo real você pode tentar assim:

```js
  function showThumbnail(filess) {
    var url = filess.value;
    var ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    if (filess.files && filess.files[0]&& (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg")) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          document.getElementById('fotoCapa').setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(filess.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" onchange="showThumbnail(this);"/>


<div class="imagem">
  <img id="fotoCapa" src="https://return-true.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/jquery-tabs-html5-history.png">
</div>
```

Se quiser salvar essa imagem pode utilizar ajax ou enviar como um formulário.

A respeito do ajax em JavaScript puro esse site possui um exemplo completo: [**SITE**](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html)

Comment: É isso mesmo, só que teria de ser sem jquery. Precisaria que fosse em javascript puro.

E como faz para salvar em ajax para ficar gravado na página, há algum site, tutorial para ensinar? Obrigado desde já!

Comment: @Intube editei minha resposta para javascript puro